# How to calculate mean of values per unique class

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
sex   age
f     10
m     12
m     11
m     17
f     13
f     12
I     8
```

Want I want to calculate the **mean** of `age` per sex:

```
f=> mean age = (10+13+12) /3
m=> mean age = (12+11+17) /3
I=> mean age = 8
```

I am trying something like this:

```
combine(df, :age => mean => :mean_age, :sex => unique)
```

But all mean_age have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` first:

```
combine(groupby(df, :sex), :age => mean => :mean_age)
```

or using DataFramesMeta.jl

```
@chain df begin
    groupby(:sex)
    @combine(:mean_age = mean(:age))
end
```